# change title with variable in v-tab with vue.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

Hi wanna change the infos title with this varibale {{ siteParts.serial_no }}
how can i do this ?

```
 <v-tab title="infos">
 <div v-for="siteParts in sitePartGSM">
 {{ siteParts.serial_no }}
 <div class="description" v-for="item in siteParts.part_attributes">
 <small><strong>{{item.x_name}}</strong> {{item.x_value}}</small>
 </div>
 </div>
 </v-tab>
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understood your question... `v-tab` is outside the `div` with `v-for` (which is an array). So you can set a `v-tab` for each `sitePartGSM` or just show the title for a specific item.

1st solution:

```
 <div v-for="siteParts in sitePartGSM">
     <v-tab :title="siteParts.serial_no">
```

2nd: solution:

```
 <v-tab :title="sitePartGSM[0].serial_no" v-if="sitePartGSM[0]">
     <div v-for="siteParts in sitePartGSM">
```

In both case remember to add `:` before `title` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) to achieve that.

Comment: hi can you show me how exactelly please because am still trying no success thanks